# PHP Normalizer doesn't show different result

Tags: php

I'd like to use the [normalizer class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php) to achieve something like:

'ö ä ü é ô' => 'o a u e o'

I ran this php-script:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
echo Normalizer::normalize('ö ä ü é ô', Normalizer::FORM_C);
```

the result is:

```
ö ä ü é ô
```

So there is no difference to the input. What can I do?

Comment: That's not what the normalizer does, your expectations are wrong. There are many other questions for how to "remove diacritics from characters", look at those.

Comment: Ok, this is where my expectaions came from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284118/convert-national-chars-into-their-latin-equivalents-in-php

Comment: Wow, that's just... wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There really isn't a direct way to do this, but with iconv you can change the charset of the string to another charset that doesn't have those accents, and if you use //TRANSLIT it will instead use the closest approximation.

You can find several examples in the User Contributed Notes at: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php.

E: you can also do this with the Normalizer class:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
$text = "ö ü ä";
echo preg_replace('/\pM*/u','',normalizer_normalize( $text, Normalizer::FORM_D));
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `Normalizer` you should use [`Transliterator`](http://php.net/transliterator)

```php
$str = 'ö ä ü é ô';
echo Transliterator::create('Latin-ASCII')->transliterate($str);
```