# Replace Polish characteres with standard ascii equivalent

Tags: php, regex, linux, iteration, ascii

Basically, I have a huge amount of files and many of them contain polish letters like 'ł, ż, ź, ó, ń' etc. in their filename.

What I want to reach is somehow change this polish letter to standard ascii character. (So for example ż => z, ń => n).

The files are located on the server with Linux Debian Squeezee.

What should I use and how to achieve the final effect?

Comment: [iconv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to a charset like ISO-8869-1 with transliteration perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put a PHP tag to your question, so my answer will consider that.

There is a question similiar to yours.

> [Convert national chars into their latin equivalents in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284118/convert-national-chars-into-their-latin-equivalents-in-php)

---

### Basically

Use Normalizer PHP extension.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php

```
<?php
    $string = 'ł ż ź ó ń';
    echo Normalizer::normalize($string);
?>
```